# How to display (echo) a large json file in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a json file and I know the location of it. let us say C:\desktop\file. I am adding a bash script in an existing application that would read this bash script take the output and use the json that it extracts for something else. How would I go about doing that.

output should be something like

```
echo Start
echo C:\desktop\file
echo End
```

The file is also large

Comment: You could open it in an editor, or use a command like `less` to display it in your terminal screen-by-screen.

Comment: @larsks yes but I need it to be displayed fully so that it can be read by another program and not in an editor

Comment: As @larsks says, you can see it yourself with `less`. If you want to read it with another program you can redirect the stdin like this `your_program < your_json_file` or alternatively, pipe it from another command like this `cat your_json_file | your_program`

Comment: You need to be more clear about what it is you're trying to do. You asked how to show what's inside the file, and in my comment I told you how to do exactly that. If you're trying to do something specific, please update your question with additional information.

Comment: Thanks @larsks. I updated my question. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: What needs the json fed into it? No- your question is not clear. As mentioned by @Miguel you would normally pipe it by what you describe in your vague question. I could answer your question simply with `cat <file>` since you don't explain. That would print out the file to console.

Comment: BTW `echo` will not show a file - just the filename. `echo C:\desktop\file` gives:  `C:\desktop\file` - not the file contents. Under windows CMD the basic command to display file contents is `type`. Under Bash it's `cat`.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone i was jumping the gun. Thought it would be more complicated than I thought. cat works just fine.